# How to pull the right information from struct proplist JSON objects

Tags: json, parsing, erlang

After using mochijson2 to decode the JSON data, I get this structred proplist.

```
 {struct,
 [{<<"query">>,
  {struct,
  [{<<"count">>,4},
   {<<"created">>,<<"2013-11-08T18:33:07Z">>},
   {<<"lang">>,<<"en-US">>},
   {<<"results">>,
    {struct,
        [{<<"quote">>,
          [{struct,
               [{<<"symbol">>,<<"YHOO">>},
                {<<"Ask">>,<<"32.99">>},
                {<<"AverageDailyVolu"...>>,<<"18383000">>},
                {<<"Bid">>,<<"32.98">>},
                {<<"AskRealt"...>>,<<"32.9"...>>},
                {<<"BidR"...>>,<<...>>},
                {<<...>>,...},
                {...}|...]},
```

As you can see above, I want to get to the [{struct, [{<<"symbol">>,<<"YHOO">>}]] ... etc, and start pull out the data from there. This is how far I've come, but I can't seem to get it out. Any help is appreciated!

```
Struct = mochijson2:decode(Body), Struct,
{struct, JsonData} = Struct,
{struct, Symbol} = proplists:get_value(<<"query">>, JsonData),
{struct, New} = proplists:get_value(<<"results">>, Symbol),
{struct, New1} = proplists:get_value(<<"quote">>, New),
 Id = proplists:get_value(<<"symbol">>, New1),
 Id.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression

```
{struct, New1} = proplists:get_value(<<"quote">>, New),
```

contains an incorrect matching. Correctly so:

```
[{struct, New1}] = proplists:get_value(<<"quote">>, New),
```

Comment: Oh, I did that. But I got an error on that line now, saying "** exception error: no match of right hand side value".

Comment: This work for me and rerturns <<"YHOO">>:

`Struct = mochijson2:decode(Body),
{struct, JsonData} = Struct,
{struct, Symbol} = proplists:get_value(<<"query">>, JsonData),
{struct, New} = proplists:get_value(<<"results">>, Symbol),
[{struct, New1}] = proplists:get_value(<<"quote">>, New),
 Id = proplists:get_value(<<"symbol">>, New1),
 Id.`

Your code is the same?

Comment: Oh, `New` contains a list of structs. You can use this: `[{struct, New1}|_] = proplists:get_value(<<"quote">>, New)` to get first of them or something like `New1 = proplists:get_value(<<"quote">>, New),
    [proplists:get_value(<<"symbol">>, S) || {struct, S} <- New1]` to get all "symbol" values.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you I understand what you mean! But if I do it with the list comprehension, how can I get a few selective data from it for example all the <<"symbol">>, <<"Ask">>, <<"bid">> in one list but not the rest?

Comment: For example: `[{proplists:get_value(<<"symbol">>, S), proplists:get_value(<<"Ask">>, S), proplists:get_value(<<"Bid">>, S)} || {struct, S} <- New1]`. Result: `[{<<"YHOO">>,<<"33.59">>,<<"33.26">>}, {<<"AAPL">>,<<"521.65">>,<<"520.90">>}, {<<"GOOG">>,<<"1038.20">>,<<"999.00">>}, {<<"MSFT">>,<<"37.75">>,<<"37.70">>}]`

Answer (score 0):

Why mochijson2? Try https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx It is very simple and does not create the atom struct so so the pattern matching easier (fewer characters), because once creates proplist.